# Can I force an update to a Textbox DataContext bound to a ComboBox.SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, undo

I am implementing an undo/redo functionality for my application and have ran into a problem.  Basically I have a combo box bound to a list of items.  Then I have several text boxes that have a DataContext of the selected item in the combo box and text bound to properties of that item.  When a user issues an Undo Command and the item to be undone is the textual changes of a text box, I want the associated item in the combo box to be selected first.  Then, I want to immediately update the textbox with the original text.  This should, in theory, update the data bound property of the selected item.  What's happening, however, is that the selection changes, but the databound textboxes are not updated before I change the textbox's text property and therefore it is changing the property value on the previously selected item in the combo box.

This is my combo box:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectionChanged="myComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

This is my text box (the DataContext is set on the parent Grid.  The same behavior occurs if the DataContext is set on the textbox itself)

```
<TextBox x:Name="purposeTxtBox" 
         Text="{Binding Purpose, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The code (snippet) I am using once the undo is initiated is:

```
case UndoAction.PURPOSE_CHANGE:
    SelectComboBoxItem(myComboBox, itemToSelect);
    purposeTxtBox.Text = itemValue;
    FocusAndSelect(purposeTxtBox);
```

And the SelectComboBoxItem method:

```
private void SelectComboBoxItem(ComboBox box, object item)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
                           new Action(delegate()
                           {
                               box.SelectedItem = item;
                           }));
}
```

I know I can update the 'Purpose' property on my DataContext.  That does work but it doesn't focus and select if I do it that way.  Plus, since all the bindings are already in place and some of them bind to integers, I was going to just update the text and allow the 'magic' to handle the translations.  That way I could have a general solution for any textbox. For completeness sake, here is my FocusAndSelect function:

```
private void FocusAndSelect(TextBox box)
{
    box.SelectAll();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
                           new Action(delegate()
                           {
                               box.Focus();         // Set Logical Focus
                               Keyboard.Focus(box); // Set Keyboard Focus
                           }));
}
```

Comment: Side comment: the undo can be organized by adding delegate to the list of delegates, which will simple set some property value back. Then undo is a simple call of this delegate and removing it from the list.

Comment: @Sinatr, do you have an example of what you describe that you could point me to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
                       new Action(delegate()
                       {
                           box.SelectedItem = item;
                       }));
```

You're telling the system to update the combo box value, but you're using an asynchronous method (I think). This means it's going to do it when it can on the UI thread (though I think you're calling it from the UI thread) but anyway - it's not going to happen **now**.

Then in the next line, you're setting purposeTxtBox.Text = itemValue directly, but the checkbox has not yet updated it's selected value, so the value-changed has not been performed yet.

Ultimately, the issue is you're mixing your logic with your UI. You shouldn't be changing the selected value by going into the UI and changing something so your data gets updated. You should be changing the data directly, and letting the UI update itself when it needs.

To take a simple example, with a checkbox displaying boolean, you don't want to create a checkbox in the UI and check it and uncheck it in your business logic or data logic, the checkbox shouldn't be holding that value - your program should, and the checkbox should just bind to it. You need to change that value to false, you make the boolean false, not go to the checkbox, set that to unchecked and let the binding update the boolean. That's kind of going about things backwards!

What you should be doing is having this:

```
    private Item selectedItem;
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItem != value)
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                //perform your ItemChange events here, if you have any
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }
```

Your combo box should bind it's SelectedItem to that property. Your text boxes should bind their text properties to the grid's data context SelectedItem.SomeText properties.

When you change the selection, you don't then go to the UI, change the component, wait for the UI thread to process that, come back, trigger an event etc etc etc

You just change the object - the UI reacts.

That's much better practice. This is also why we have models like MVVM and MVC, to force this divide between UI and logic.

Comment: Hi @Joe,  Thank you for your detailed response.  I am trying to do as you said.  I have updated the binding to the ComboBox and the Grid using a SelectedItem property.  That seems to be working great as far as the binding is concerned.  However, if I do that and then do SelectedItem = item; item.Purpose = "Some text"; the UI is not responding.  I should mention, since you brought it up that these calls are actually in another class.  That is why I was using the Dispatcher.Invoke... perhaps I have misunderstood what that is doing?

Comment: Is the UI not updating, as in the combobox not changing it's selected item? Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on your data context? How are you binding it? Are you using Mode=TwoWay?

Comment: You need to use Dispatcher.Invoke when you're trying to directly change the UI in another thread (not the UI thread).

If you are just binding to a property, you can update that property from any thread and the UI manages updating itself - it should update if INotifyPropertyChanged and the mode is correct!

Comment: Yes it is a Mode=TwoWay binding.  As a test, I set it programmatically in the constructor and it did update the UI.  It also updates the data item when it is changed through the combobox.  It appears not to be updating the UI when it is called from this other class however.

Comment: This appears to be an issue elsewhere in the code.  I have verified the SelectedItem has changed but it is changing it due to another issue.  I will track the reason down but it is unrelated.  Thank you for your help @Joe.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your problem (I hope it will be useful), but you can organize undo with delegates:

```
readonly Stack<Action> _undo = new Stack<Action>();

string _someProperty;
// property to bind
public string SomeProperty
{
    get { return _someProperty; }
    set
    {
        var old = _someProperty; // capture old value
        _undo.Push(() =>
        {
            _someProperty = old;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        });
        _someProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

void Undo()
{
    if (_undo.Count > 0)
        _undo.Pop()();
}
```

Changing property value (via binding) will *record* delegate which set previous value. Calling `Undo()` will simply *play* delegates from last to first (LIFO).

You can add selection and focus manipulations into delegate too (not sure if this is a good idea).